# How do I convert this pandas groupby into Dask groupby to parallelize it?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I'm pulling data which is grouped by timestamp and iterating over each group and performing calculations and storing the result into an appended dataframe. It gets really slow when the amount of data is large and it can definitely be parallelized because each group is not dependent on another. This is the code I have right now:

```
def get_distance_from_mid_for_size(self,size):
    dfg = self._df.groupby(self._df.index)
    spread_df = pd.DataFrame(index=dfg.groups.keys())
    for timestamp, data in dfg:
        data = data.sort_values(by='level')
        mid_price = (data.bid_price[0]*data.ask_size[0] + data.ask_price[0]*data.bid_size[0])/(data.bid_size[0] + data.ask_size[0])
        spread_df.loc[timestamp, 'bid_spread'] = mid_price - self.get_average_price(data, size, 'bid')
        spread_df.loc[timestamp, 'ask_spread'] = self.get_average_price(data, size, 'ask') - mid_price
        spread_df.loc[timestamp, 'mid_price'] = mid_price

    return spread_df
```

I want to use Dask and the groupby function on that but seems like it's only for aggregate functions? I'm totally lost on how to implement what I have above.

Link to the data is here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kkl9pxuf8oypmvz/sample.csv?dl=0

Comment: Hi bloodynri, do you mind to share a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) [mcve2](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports)

Comment: Here is the link to the data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kkl9pxuf8oypmvz/sample.csv?dl=0

Comment: http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports